# How do you retrieve API site names from /associated?

Tags: support, api

The [`/associated`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users) API call returns an array of [`network_user`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user) objects, each of which looks like this:

```
{
  "badge_counts": {
    "bronze": 1,
    "silver": 2,
    "gold": 3
  },
  "question_count": 25,
  "answer_count": 50,
  "last_access_date": 1489836385,
  "creation_date": 1489793185,
  "account_id": 1,
  "reputation": 9001,
  "user_id": 1,
  "site_url": "http://example.stackexchange.com/",
  "site_name": "Example Site"
}
```

The only fields there that identify the site are `site_url` and `site_name`.

All of the rest of the per-site API calls take a `site` query parameter, whose value is some string that does not appear to be included in the above results. For example `stackoverflow`, `russian`, or `woodworking`.

So my question is: Given a `network_user`, how do I determine what the corresponding `site` query parameter value is for that site?

For example, an application that queries for associated accounts, then performs an operation on one of those sites. This seems like a relatively straightforward use case, but I am not sure how to make it work.

Comment: You can actually [just pass in the domain name](http://stackapps.com/questions/4257/give-us-a-sites-api-name-in-the-list-of-a-users-sites), fwiw

Comment: Or match `site_url` from [`/sites`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) and use the corresponding `site_url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292593/how-do-you-retrieve-api-site-names-from-associated?noredirect=1#comment950539_292593) and [Nathan Tuggy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292593/how-do-you-retrieve-api-site-names-from-associated?noredirect=1#comment950541_292593) both gave good answers in comments so I'll just summarize here. There are at least two options.

### Option 1: Use the domain name as the site parameter.

The site parameter can be the domain name of the site. See https://stackapps.com/a/4258/25350 and also the [API docs](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs), up at the top of the "Per-Site Methods" section, which reads:

> This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by api_site_parameter on the [site object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site).

So you can strip the `http://` off the front of the `network_user.site_url`, strip trailing slashes if there are any (the example object includes them although in practice they don't seem to be there), and use that directly.

### Option 2: Find the site in `/sites` and retrieve the API parameter.

The other option is to make a query to [`/sites`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites), which returns [site objects](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site) that have both a `site_url` and an `api_site_parameter` field.

Then you match the `site_url` with your `network_user.site_url`, and use the corresponding API site parameter.

---

It seems a little strange that `network_user` doesn't include `api_site_parameter` but, it's no big deal, both of these strategies are straightforward. The fact that the parameter takes domain names makes up for it, the corresponding required string manipulation is a negligible inconvenience.